# I can't start a virtualenv from a shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

The script is to open a new terminal and access a directory, activate the virtual environment inside him, and then run my service within that environment:

```
#!/bin/bash
gnome-terminal -- bash -c "cd mydirectory/project && source ~/myenv/bin/activate && python3 run.py runserver; exec bash"
```

But when you run it, don't activate the environment. The other commands works.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Would you think it could help to show the contents of the 'activate' script?

Comment: @Twonky You can see the contents if you create a virtualenv on your local machine.

Comment: The `exec bash` would start a new shell process which has not sourced the virtualenv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a shell file ~/mydirectory/project/runserver.sh as :

```
cd $HOME/mydirectory/project
source ~/myenv/bin/activate
python3 run.py runserver
```

Then run:

```
gnome-terminal -- bash --rcfile ~/mydirectory/project/runserver.sh
```

Comment: Kind of. I want to access a directory, activate the virtual environment, and then run my service within that environment. I modified the question to explain better. Sorry for my mistake.